# Unable to deploy google app engine app python on windows

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a website on app engine - uses python. We have updated the site - to a more modern bootstrap affair. We can now no longer deploy it we get the following error:

```
2017-04-11 22:27:17 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--oauth2_credential_file=C:\\Users\\spydre/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens', 'update', 'C:\\Users\\spydre\\ashfordchroming2015']"
10:27 PM Application: ashfordchroming2015; version: 1
10:27 PM Host: appengine.google.com
10:27 PM Starting update of app: ashfordchroming2015, version: 1
10:27 PM Getting current resource limits.
10:27 PM Scanning files on local disk.
Could not guess mimetype for static/plugins/jquery-1.11.1.min.map.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for static/plugins/rs-plugin/font/revicons.eot.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for static/plugins/rs-plugin/assets/arrows.psd.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for static/plugins/rs-plugin/assets/bullets.psd.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for static/plugins/rs-plugin/assets/small_arrows.psd.  Using application/octet-stream.
10:27 PM Scanned 500 files.
Could not guess mimetype for static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.map.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for static/plugins/rs-plugin/assets/small_arrows.psd.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.map.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for static/plugins/rs-plugin/assets/bullets.psd.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for static/plugins/rs-plugin/assets/arrows.psd.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for static/plugins/rs-plugin/font/revicons.eot.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for static/plugins/jquery-1.11.1.min.map.  Using application/octet-stream.
10:27 PM Cloning 476 static files.
10:27 PM Cloning 119 application files.
10:27 PM Uploading 249 files and blobs.
2017-04-11 22:29:29,138 ERROR appcfg.py:2587 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2425, in DoUpload
    self._UploadMissingFiles(missing_files, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2554, in _UploadMissingFiles
    self.UploadFile(missing_file, file_handle)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2055, in UploadFile
    file_classification.StaticMimeType())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1477, in AddToBatch
    self.SendSingleFile(path, payload, mime_type)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1423, in SendSingleFile
    path=path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1719, in Send
    result = self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 246, in Send
    url, method=method, body=payload, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\oauth2client\oauth2client\client.py", line 569, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1584, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1332, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1306, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1053, in connect
    raise socket.error, msg
error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
10:29 PM Rolling back the update.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5510, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5501, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2975, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5157, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3889, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3942, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3824, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2425, in DoUpload
    self._UploadMissingFiles(missing_files, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2554, in _UploadMissingFiles
    self.UploadFile(missing_file, file_handle)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2055, in UploadFile
    file_classification.StaticMimeType())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1477, in AddToBatch
    self.SendSingleFile(path, payload, mime_type)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1423, in SendSingleFile
    path=path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1719, in Send
    result = self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 246, in Send
    url, method=method, body=payload, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\oauth2client\oauth2client\client.py", line 569, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1584, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1332, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1306, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1053, in connect
    raise socket.error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
2017-04-11 22:29:31 (Process exited with code 1)
```

We are using windows 10 have downloaded the latest CLI and are running on Python. However the site is running on webapp python 2.5. We have not upgraded it to 2.7.

Comment: Is the Google platform down?

Comment: Not that I know of - the site is running, the old version.

Comment: It looks like the push is failing.   Is possible that that part is down on their end.

Comment: status looks good what's on line appcfg.py:2587 of the configuration file?

Comment: How would i find that, that is not in the app folder right?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py

Comment: I don't have that file at that location?

Comment: It has deployed  - I retried this must be 15 times - had to rollback a few times. It took 14 mins to upload. I think your first assumption was correct some sort of issue with app engine. Thanks for your help